# initiate attribute A depending on attributes B and C effectively

Tags: java, initialization, abstract, superclass

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    public int x, y;
    public int z = x + y;
}
```

every subclass of SuperClass should have attributes x, y and z. But while x and y could be different for all subclasses and must therefore manually be initiated, how can I be smart about initiating z?
i.e. I don't want to call `z = x + y` in every subclass of SuperClass.

Comment: First of all, they are private. Sub classes won't be able to see them. Rephrase what you want.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Let's make them public then. What I want to accomplish doesn't change.

Comment: Why not use `protected` instead?!

Comment: Easy, give `x` and `y` default values and then create a no arg constructor with `z = x + y;` every subclass will run the no arg super constructor when they are run.

Comment: @oschlueter Well, in my case I use public access because other classes need acces to the specific values of the subclasses. But I don't understand why that matters?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis was pointing out that the variables were private which apparently let you make them public. I just wanted to point out that there's an alternative x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to call z = x + y in every subclass of SuperClass.

Just give z a default value in your superclass then, e.g. x+y, or leave it blank if you wish.   Then in the subclass, define z as you want in the constructor.

```
public class SuperClass{

int x, y, z;

SuperClass(int x, int y){

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    //pick a default value of z;
    z = x + y;
}
```

}

```
public class Example extends SuperClass {

Example(int x, int y){
    super(x , y);

    //pick another z implementation here;
    z = x * y ^ x;
}
```

}

Comment: Answered 17 minutes ago? I could only see your answer for 15 something seconds and then it disappeared. That was weird.

Comment: I had typos, I pulled it to correct them...  I check in eclipse my syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Make `x` an `y` `protected` or make them avaiable to the sub classes via the appropriate getter and setter methods. Otherwise subclasses won't see them.
To initialize z, you could set it in the the constructor of your `SuperClass` like:

```
Superclass(int x, int y)
{
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = x + y;
}
```

In your inherited classes then use `super(x,y)` in their constructor to call the constructor of the `SuperClass`.

Now that's about initializing them... I don't know, what you want to achieve, but if you want to change `x` and `y` so that `z` is kept consisently as `x + y`, you have to do that manually. One way to achieve this is to calculate z in the setter methods of `x` and `y`.

**Edit:**
Corresponding setters:

```
void setX(int x)
{
   this.x = x;
   z = x + y;
}

void setY(int y)
{
   this.y = y;
   z = x + y;
}
```

Comment: Well.. x and y are unknown before the contruction of the individual subclass. I can't give them any logical default values; which means I can't define `z = x + y` in the super constructor because it will need to be called before initializing x and y in the subclass.

Comment: the calculate the value for `z` in the corresponding setter methods like I suggested. that's the simplest solution here.

Comment: +1 for recalculating `z` in the setter methods. That comes pretty close to solving their problem as I understand it. Might be worth marking them final to stop subclasses from breaking the recalculation if they override them.

Comment: No, it's not all it. It makes no sense. But this question was answered by someone who took down their post. He told me to define an SuperClass(x, y) constructor which solves my problem: Computes z without me having to type extra.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't make sense? It's exactly the same as the other answer was. You could always call the `SuperClass` constructor with default values, you shouldn't be afraid of typing since it's not that much. Also `integer`'s default value is 0. **Edit:* Now that the other answer is back again, it's excactly the same.

Comment: @Zhedar I'm sorry, I don't understand how it is the same. As for not typing much that is completely irrelevant since I will potentially have 100 different attributes solely functional dependancies of x and y. Which could become a lot. It's a matter of learning and understanding Java here :-)

Comment: Well it's the same, since I wrote you then call `super(x,y);` in your sub classes' constructor ;)

Comment: Yeah I see, it is exactly the same. Don't know what got me confused! Sorry, hehe.